# Parse text divided by <br> but not inside <span>

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I can't figure out how to parse this type of data:

```
<div id="tabs-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">



            <strong><span itemprop="name">MOS-SCHAUM</span></strong><br>
        <span itemprop="description">Antistatická pena čierna na IO 300x300x6mm</span>


        <br>RoHS: Áno           
        <br>Obj.číslo: 13291<br>



        </div>
```

There can be many `<span>` tags inside the snippet - I don't want to get them. I want only those, which are not inside `<span>` tags.

So the result would be:

```
{'RoHS':'Áno',
 'Obj.číslo': '13291'}
```

I was considering `.contents` but it's a very unpredictable which elements will be on which index.

Do you know how to do that?

EDIT: 
Even if I try this:

```
detail_table = soup.find('div',id="tabs-1")                              
itemprops = detail_table.find_all('span',itemprop=re.compile('.+'))      
for item in itemprops:                                                   
    data[item['itemprop']]=item                                          

contents = detail_table.contents[-1].contents[-1].contents[-1].contents

for i,c in enumerate(contents):
print c                    
print '---'
```

I get this:

```
RoHS: Áno           
                                 # 1st element
---
<br>Obj.Ä�Ã­slo: 68664<br>
</br></br>                        # 2st element
---
```

EDIT2: I've just find out one solution but it's not very nice. There must be a more elegant solution:

```
def get_data(url):                                                                 
    data = {}                                                                      
    soup = get_soup(url)                                                           

    """ TECHNICAL INFORMATION """                                                  
    tech_par_table = soup.find('div',id="tabs-2")                                  
    trs = tech_par_table.find_all('tr')                                            
    for tr in trs:                                                                 
        tds = tr.find_all('td')                                                    
        parameter = tds[0].text                                                    
        value = tds[1].text                                                        
        data[parameter]=value                                                      

    """ DETAIL """                                                                 
    detail_table = soup.find('div',id="tabs-1")                                    
    itemprops = detail_table.find_all('span',itemprop=re.compile('.+'))            
    for item in itemprops:                                                         
        data[item['itemprop'].replace('\n','').replace('\t','').strip()]=item.text.

    contents = detail_table.contents[-1].contents[-1].contents[-1].contents        

    for i,c in enumerate(contents):                                                
        if isinstance(c,bs4.element.NavigableString):                              
            splitted = c.split(':')                                                
            data[splitted[0]]=splitted[1].replace('\n','').replace('\t','').strip()
        if isinstance(c,bs4.element.Tag):                                          
            splitted = c.text.split(':')                                           
            data[splitted[0]]=splitted[1].replace('\n','').replace('\t','').strip()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to get all `br` tag and use the [`.next_element`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-element-and-previous-element) attribute to get whatever was parsed immediately after each `br` tag; here your text.

```
d = {}

for br in soup.find_all('br'):
    text = br.next_element.strip()
    if text:
        arr = text.split(':')
        d[arr[0]] = arr[1].strip()
print(d)
```

yields:

```
{'Obj.číslo': '13291', 'RoHS': 'Áno'}
```